# How to convert iOS id type which holds int to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, nsstring, nsobject

I have an `id` which holds an `int`. I need to cast it to an `NSString` and append it to another `NSString`.

I've trued different approaches but I have different type of errors. My confusion is that `int` is not an object type.

My code is:

```
NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:ID]];
```

In this case I have `(int) 1000`.

When I try to append it to `NSString` I get an exception.

How can I properly cast from an `id`, which holds `int`, to `NSString` ?

Comment: When you say `id`, do you mean the Objective-C object type, or something else?

Comment: id stands for "unknown object type" so already holds an object not just an int. How do you get the id object? There should be a hint what object will be inside. Usually a call to integerValue should give you the integer value and is implemented for most objects

Comment: I get `id` from reading `NSDictionary` value - see my code. When I try some of the casts it tells me something like: you try to use `int` but your var is `id`. And yes - I mean iOS `id`.

Comment: when an id object holds a numeric value, you can access it as NSNumber. And then use [NSstring stringWithFormat:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *str = [[dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:ID]] stringValue];
```

Comment: Or `NSString *str = [dict[@(ID)] stringValue];`.